# Inheriting view model and changing DisplayName data annotations

Tags: c#, inheritance, data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a view model which I am inheriting from a base class view model. I am trying to change the DisplayName metadata in the inherited class but it's not working.

Here are the view models:

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class BaseViewModel
    {
        [DisplayName(Name = "Base Description")]
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    }

     public class DerivedViewModel : BaseViewModel
     {
        [DisplayName(Name = "Derived Description")]
        public override string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the controller:

```
    public ViewResult Create()
    {
        DerivedViewModel model = new DerivedViewModel();
        model.Active = true;
        return View(model);
    }
```

When the view is rendered, the expected display name is "Derived Description" but instead I'm getting "Base Description".

Using: MVC 5.1, .NET Framework 4.5, Visual Studio 2013

Can anyone tell me how to override the Display data annotation in a derived class?

Comment: Do you remember if you were able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed. Brought in the latest jQuery and jQuery unobtrusive and this fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm wondering if you could explain this answer a little more. The problem you were facing in the original question seems exactly what I'm facing. However, I don't understand how JQuery has anything to do with display name? Perhaps this answer was intended for a different question?